# Get documentforce.com domain URL in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, mydomain

I am rendering content document previews in my LWC component by placing `<img src>` tags into the DOM.

The link i use looks like this:

`/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/renditionDownload/?rendition=THUMB720BY480&versionId={lastVersionId}`

The user accesses the page via `https://<MyDomain>.lightning.force.com`

Unfortunately, it seems that my org responds with a 302 to `https://<MyDomain>.my.salesforce.com`; and that again responds with a redirect (301 this time) to `https://<MyDomain>--c.documentforce.com`.

So for each image i render, the browser makes 3 requests. I load images in batches of 50, so the browser makes 151 requests and that is not very performant.

Considering this is a managed package, so i can't just hardcode the URL, is there a way to get the `documentforce.com` domain in LWC somehow? (or at least in Apex so i can supply it from the backend).

Comment: what exactly are you using this for ? for preview? or for showing array of images with some details besides them?

Comment: both of those, actually.

Comment: Have you tried `window.location.origin` as per [this blog post](https://www.salesforcecodecrack.com/2020/01/salesforce-base-url-in-lwc.html)?

Comment: @BrianMiller that gives you `https://<MyDomain>.lightning.force.com`, as my original post says, i need `https://<MyDomain>--c.documentforce.com`

Comment: I hear, thanks for explaining it out

Comment: @zaitsman Did you find out how to do it?

Comment: @pmehta28 sadly, no. I added a setting to my package for admins to enter it.

Comment: @zaitsman This is how I am doing : `String vUrl = 'https://' + Url.getSalesforceBaseUrl().getHost();
        system.debug(vUrl);
        String instanceName = [select InstanceName from Organization limit 1].InstanceName;
        system.debug(instanceName);
        vUrl = vUrl.replace('.my.salesforce.','--c.'+instanceName+'.content.force.');
        system.debug(vUrl);
        return vUrl;`

Comment: @pmehta28 that only works for some orgs. In some i saw that url also redirect to `domain--c.documentforce.com` and i found nothing on why it does that :( and as an ISV i need a universal solution that works everywhere

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any way to get the host URL of the file, however, this isn't the case when you want to get the download URL of the file. Salesforce itself loads the preview of images from another domain.
If you query on ContentDistribution with the ContentVersionId.

```
SELECT ContentVersionId, Id, ContentDownloadUrl, DistributionPublicUrl FROM ContentDistribution
```

You'll see Download Url does have the actual URL where the file is hosted. However, PublicUrl doesn't.
I know this doesn't answer your question, but since you're concerned about the no. of requests made to show the image. So you can either trim the URL, you'd only need the instance path from the URL. This should work,

```
Id cvId = cv.Id; //ContentVersion Id
String docUrl = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm().split('-dev-ed.')[0];
docUrl = docUrl + '-dev-ed--c.documentforce.com/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/'+cvId+'?operationContext=S1';
```

This is the only way you can leverage additional server calls.

### UPDATE: 01/02/2022

Now since Enhanced domains are being enforced, the structure of the host path of the files hosted in Salesforce is consistent. And we also have an Standard apex class to return the host name of the Salesforce org.

> Use the DomainCreator class to return a hostname specific to the org.
> For example, get the org’s Visualforce hostname. Values are returned
> as a hostname, such as MyDomainName.lightning.force.com.

It can now be done simply using `DomainCreator.getOrgMyDomainHostname();`

Comment: You see how you put `documentforce.com` there. I have a couple of subscriber orgs where the previews are actually in `na16.force.com` or similar format as they are older than documentforce. So that won't work for me because i can't tell :)

Comment: You can perform an additional check. If the org **doesn't have my domain enabled**. The download URL will be, baseurl +'/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/'+versionId+'?operationContext=S1'. That's what I can tell.

Comment: the orgs i refer to DO have my domain enabled because without my domain custom lightning flexipages don't even work.

Comment: Then check the actual url where file is hosted. The pattern is similar for all.

Comment: this query returns nothing for content versions that I can query via `ContentDocumentLink`. I am not sure why these are not created for them.

Comment: Note that querying ContentDistribution is a good way to get the domain name but there might be no ContentDistribution record if no public share exists in the org. So you can't rely on it if you want to package your solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way as of now in LWC. From Apex, you can get the URL like below:

```
String vUrl = 'https://' + Url.getSalesforceBaseUrl().getHost() + '/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/renditionDownload.........' ;
```

You will notice that in this way, there is no `documentforce` in the URL, but the final URL really works. I can say this because I have worked on a similar kind of scenario a week back.

Comment: What do you mean by ‘really works’?? The base url gives me the lightning.force.com one

Comment: (Actually, in some orgs i get the `https://<MyDomain>.my.salesforce.com` which is the second hop, but it's still a hop. I want to get the documentforce.com one)

Answer (score 0):

As an ISV I think your biggest concern here is regarding your namespace appearing on the URL or not. I think, however, that document URLs do not use this separation, being a common feature of the platform for all tenants and all.

What I would do is get the organization's name using `Url.getSalesforceBaseUrl().getHost()` and use it to generate the documentforce dynamically whenever necessary (having a method in my LWCs to call an Apex method that returned that information, for example).

This snippet generates the URL on the debug logs depending on your current environment.

```
String s = Url.getSalesforceBaseUrl().getHost();
String prefix = s.split('.my')[0];

if (prefix.contains('--')) {
    System.debug('Sandbox instance.');
    System.debug(prefix + '--c.documentforce.com');
} else {
    System.debug('Production instance.');
    System.debug(prefix + '.documentforce.com');
}
```

It is easy to turn this into an invocable/Aura enabled method to return the correct string. It can be a one-liner in your Apex:

```
return Url.getSalesforceBaseUrl().getHost().split('.my')[0].contains('--')
    ? (prefix + '--c.documentforce.com')
    : (prefix + '.documentforce.com')
```

As such:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static String getDocumentForceUrl() {
    String prefix = Url.getSalesforceBaseUrl().getHost().split('.my')[0];
    return prefix.contains('--')
        ? (prefix + '--c.documentforce.com')
        : (prefix + '.documentforce.com');
}
```

And to future-proof this, you might want to store this information in a custom setting hidden from your subscribers, and calculate/set it up on installation (using a class with the `InstallHandler` interface). That way you would be able to generate it as necessary with new Salesforce releases (in case Salesforce breaks the URL or you find another way of setting this up).

Another way I see of doing this is to generate a dummy ContentVersion and ContentDistribution at install time, and query the ContentDownloadUrl as suggested by another answer for this same question. That way you would be able to check what the prefix is and store it somewhere (as I suggested above).

Comment: This simply does not work in all orgs. We have a customer where the `--c.documentforce.com` URL does NOT work despite them having MyDomain, as this is an older org. If i wanted to do a split like so, I could do it in javascript without calling Apex.

Comment: And no, my concern has nothing to do with my namespace whatsoever. The issue I have is that SF is inconsistent with documentforce URLs depending on whatever legacy goes in there, and there doesn't seem to be a method of getting this out of SF itself.

Comment: The second method would work because you'd be getting the URL directly from the content distribution object's field, which should match the org's, whatever it might be, no?

Comment: @RenatoOliveira it would work only if there is a publicly shared file in the org, and if the user can see this content distribution record. To see a file in experience cloud it might work... or not